# Use OSM-Tags in Wikimedia-Template

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

I would love to be able to create templates in Wikimedia that get their variables filled from the tags of an OSM-feature.

Herefor I would provide an ID like `n4741336025` and fetch the data from https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/4741336025

The tags coming from OSM could then simply be accessible as template-variables like `{{{phone}}}` or `{{{website}}}`.

The problem is: I have no idea how to get started. How can I even get a template to fetch data and *then* render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data via OSM API like https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/4741336025 and use an extension like https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:External_Data to grab and render the data.